# PowerShell Iterate file contents matching filenames recursively in directory

Tags: powershell, match, file-copying

I have a list of filenames organized like so: *(search.txt)*

```
2KJ34DS
JSD92NS
1JNKD8A
KO1N231
ASJDOA9
```

I have a directory organized like so: *\\logs\*

```
20161201
  .\
  K2J3N4K.xml
  SDJNFK2.wav
  ASDN1JE.html
20161202
20161203
20161204
```

The contents of the dated folders in the directory are the filenames I need to match on according to the list provided within the search.txt file.

I need a powershell script that can iterate over the dated folders and copy the file matches it finds to a destination "\\logs\matches\". It should match any file extension. It would be an added bonus if I could specify a "start date" and "end date" and it only iterate between the dated folders within the start and stop date.

I have no idea where to start... can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi try Something like this (PowerShell v3 minimum)

```
$listfiles=get-content "c:\temp\search.txt"
$destination="c:\logs\matches"
$startdate=get-date -Year 2016 -Month 01 -Day 01 -Hour 0 -Minute 0 -Second 0
$enddate=get-date -Year 2017 -Month 06 -Day 24 -Hour 0 -Minute 0 -Second 0

Get-ChildItem -file -Recurse "c:\logs" | 
    where {$_.BaseName -in $listfiles -and $_.FullName -ne "$destination\$($_.Name)" -and $_.LastWriteTime -ge $startdate -and $_.LastWriteTime -le $enddate} | 
        Copy-Item  -Destination $destination -Force
```

Comment: Why v5? You're not using a single feature that isn't available in v3?

Comment: you are right; i mistakenly thought that "-file option" was active since v5 because few people use it on this site, my bad. Thank you for information, i modify my publication :)